# Cannot resolve conflicts between hexagon.css and materialize.css

Tags: html, css, materialize

I am using Responsive Hexagon Grid as my base layout. After clicking a hexagon, I want a Modal to show up. For that I'm using Materialize CSS. However, After importing materialize CSS, the hovering effect of hexagon.css is completely messed up!

Is there any way I can solve this and get original hover effect like below? I'm new to this stuff.

https://github.com/web-tiki/responsive-grid-of-hexagons

See the error here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUvH4.jpg

(You may need to Google about Materialize CSS as I'm not allowed to post more than two links here).

Comment: If you want to add more links, then you can do so without the `http://`, and someone will repair it for you. However, note that "Googling about Materialize CSS" is your job. May we see the code that you have already, edited into your question?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own question here:

The conflicting code was for h1 tag. You just have to remove bottom padding from h1 tag to get things work!